# RPi.GPIO: Check if a pin is being used

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

During development, I frequently encounter this warning, as expected. My threaded code frequently prematurely terminates during experimentation.

```
Steppers.py:26: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(gpio_pin, GPIO.OUT)
```

I'm now curious if there's a way to check if a pin is being used from within Python since I'm already being warned about it in the first place. Research doesn't turn up anything other than *disable the warning* and *fix your code*, unfortunately.

I don't see anything obvious while inspecting decompiled `RPi.GPIO`. Screen snip of what it looks like below:

[image]

```
# encoding: utf-8
# module RPi._GPIO
# from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/RPi/_GPIO.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
# by generator 1.147
""" GPIO functionality of a Raspberry Pi using Python """
# no imports
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead copy the text direct into the question: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no definitive way to know if a pin is currently being used. However, one can deduce whether a pin **might** be in use by following how RPi.GPIO checks for usage:

1. If it's an input, assume unused

   - Or if someone else is reading it and we want to write to it... it's their problem now.
2. If it's a special function pin (e.g. SPI), assume it's in use.
3. If it's an output pin and *we did not set it*, assume it's in use.

---

For #1 and #3, it can be done by interacting with the GPIO driver. [This blog post](https://www.ics.com/blog/gpio-programming-using-sysfs-interface) has much information on the topic. In order to check the GPIO pin direction (examples are in Python 3, no root required shockingly),

1. Export the pin by writing the GPIO number to `/sys/class/gpio/export`

```
with open('/sys/class/gpio/export', 'w') as f:
    f.write("5")  # Example: GPIO5
```

2. Reading whether it is an input or output

```
with open('/sys/class/gpio/gpio5/direction', 'r') as f:
    pin_direction = file.readline()  # Example: GPIO5
```

As for #2, RPi.GPIO directly reads memory to see if the pin in question is being used for a special function. Currently still investigating.

---

The warning `This channel is already in use, continuing anyway` comes from the `py_setup_channel` function in `py_gpio.c` within the RPi.GPIO [source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberry-gpio-python/).

The raw code states that:

```
  if (get_gpio_number(channel, &gpio))
     return 0;

  func = gpio_function(gpio);

  if (gpio_warnings &&                             // warnings enabled and
      ((func != 0 && func != 1) ||                 // (already one of the alt functions or
      (gpio_direction[gpio] == -1 && func == 1)))  // already an output not set from this program)
  {
     PyErr_WarnEx(NULL, "This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.", 1);
  }
```

The line `gpio_function(gpio)` (defined in `c_gpio.c`) identifies the current pin function returning 0 if input, 1 if output, or something else if it has a special function such as SPI.

`gpio_direction` is an array used by RPi.GPIO to keep track of "did we set that pin as an output". The assignment can be seen near the bottom of `py_setup_channel`.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a warning.  I don't see why it should kill your script.

I'd see if there is an entry in `/sys/class/gpio/` for the (Broadcom numbered) GPIO you want to check.

E.g. to check to see if GPIO4 (pin 7)  is in use check for the existence of `/sys/class/gpio/gpio4`

**I just checked and there is no entry in `/sys/class/gpio`.  I'm not sure what RPi.GPIO does to issue the warning.**

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks! My script dies due to other reasons and fails to cleanup (such as a stray thread). At this stage, the script is experimental. I intend to add additional safety checks, hence the question.

Comment: @PNDA What I suggested does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll dig deeper.

Comment: Reporting back. There's no specific place that the library checks. The criteria for that warning is 1.) Warnings are enabled, 2.) The pin does not have an alt function like I2C, and 3.) It's already an output prior to `GPIO.setup()` which makes sense as program interference, I presume, is only a concern when outputting (programs can share the input value). Posting an answer in a bit.

Comment: RPi.GPIO uses /sys/gpiomem although theoretically it can fall back to /sys/gpio. I don't know how it "knows" a pin has been used.

Comment: @Milliways Thanks.  I'd forgotten about `/dev/gpiomem`.  Although from what PNDA has discovered I was completely off beam anyhow.

Comment: @Milliways Your comment is correct. My previous comment was from an abstraction by RPi.GPIO apparently and was not the full story. RPi.GPIO uses `/dev/gpiomem` (`/dev/mem` fallback, requires root) to interact with the GPIO pins. It can be seen in `c_gpio.c` within the RPi.GPIO source code. This is also why the entries @joan mentioned are nonexistent; the memory access makes exporting the pins unnecessary. Interestingly, there's code to export/unexport the pins, but it's not exposed in the Python library. Future expansion?